# How to effeciently modify a large xml document slightly with Microsoft xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I would like to transform this xml:

```
<Root>
  <Result>
    <Message>
      <Header>
        <!-- Hundreds of child nodes -->        
      </Header>
      <Body>
        <Node1>
          <!-- Hundreds of child nodes -->
          <Node2>
            <!-- Hundreds of child nodes -->
            <Node3>
              <!-- Hundreds of child nodes -->
              <NodeX>value 1 to be changed</NodeX>
              <!-- Hundreds of child nodes -->
              <Node4>
                <!-- Hundreds of child nodes -->
                <NodeY>value 2 to be changed</NodeY>
              </Node4>
            </Node3>
          </Node2>          
        </Node1>        
      </Body>
      <RealValuesRoot>
        <!-- These two nodes -->
        <Value ID="1">this value must replace the value of Node X</Value>
        <Value ID="2">this value must replace the value of Node Y</Value>
      </RealValuesRoot>
    </Message>
  </Result>
  <!-- Hundreds to thousands of similar MessageRoot nodes -->
</Root>
```

Into this xml:

```
<Root>
  <Result>
    <Message>
      <Header>
        <!-- Hundreds of child nodes -->
      </Header>
      <Body>
        <Node1>
          <!-- Hundreds of child nodes -->
          <Node2>
            <!-- Hundreds of child nodes -->
            <Node3>
              <!-- Hundreds of child nodes -->
              <NodeX>this value must replace the value of Node X</NodeX>
              <!-- Hundreds of child nodes -->
              <Node4>
                <!-- Hundreds of child nodes -->
                <NodeY>this value must replace the value of Node Y</NodeY>
              </Node4>
            </Node3>
          </Node2>
        </Node1>
      </Body>
    </Message>
  </Result>
  <!-- Hundreds to thousands of similar MessageRoot nodes -->
</Root>
```

The output is almost identical to the input except for the following changes:

1. The X and Y node values must be replaced with the values of the /RealValuesRoot/Value     nodes.
2. The /RealValuesRoot node must be removed from the output.
3. The rest of the xml must remain the same in the output.

The "Value" nodes have unique IDs that represent unique xpaths in the body of the message, e.g. ID 1 refres to xpath /Message/Body/Node1/Node2/Node3/NodeX.

I have to use Microsoft’s xslt version 1.0!!

I already have an xslt that works fine and does everything I want, yet I am not satisfied with the performance!

My xslt works as follows:

1. I created a global string variable that acts like a key value pair, something like: 1:xpath1_2:xpath2_ … _N:xpathN. This variable relates the IDs of the "Value" nodes to the nodes in the message body that need to be replaced.
2. The xslt iterates the input xml recursively starting from the root node.
3. I compute the xpath for the current node then do one of the following:

   1. If the current xpath completely matches one of the xpaths in the global list then I replace its value with the value of the corresponding "Value" node and continue the iteration.
   2. If the current xpath refers to the "RealValuesRoot" node then I omit that node (don’t copy it to the output) and continue to iterate recursively.
   3. If the current xpath does not exist in the global ID-xpath string then I copy the complete node to the output and continue the iteration. (this happens e.g. in the /Message/Header node that will never contain any nodes that need to be replaced)
   4. If the current xpath partially matches one of the xpaths in the global list then I simply continue to iterate recursively until I reach one of the 3 cases above.

As said, my xslt works fine but I would like to improve the performance as much as possible, please feel free to suggest a complete new xslt logic! your ideas and suggestions are welcomed!

Comment: Are they *really* called `<Node1>`, `<Node2>` etc?

Comment: of course not :-) they are just use to express the hierarchy

Comment: Well, that influences the solution. How are they called, exactly?

Comment: +1 for posting complete and syntactically valid input and desired output and for describing your problem exactly, BTW. Most people do neither of these things.

Comment: The X and Y nodes in my example could be FirstName and LastName, the rest nodes could be anything.

Comment: This does not really help me... How does `ID="1"` map to `FirstName`? I seem to be missing something here.

Comment: ID 1 maps to FirstName like I described above in the global ID-Xpath string that looks like this:

/Message/Body/Node1/Node2/Node3/FirstName:1_/Message/Body/Node1/Node2/Node3/LastName:2......etc.

the format is xpath1:Id1_xpath2:Id2_...xpath(N):Id(N)

Comment: I understand. Is that "big endless string of XPaths and IDs" an inevitable necessity in this whole process? Because that's easily the most ill-suited way to represent this kind of data.

Comment: I know but what is the alternative? I have to identify the nodes using xpath

Comment: You could start by giving the whole thing structure, instead of throwing all those bits into one big blob. I'm also thinking - if you have a way of getting 1000 XPaths and the values that the respective target nodes are supposed to have, why writing down those XPaths in the first place? Can't you just replace matching nodes right-away?

Comment: I have to identify the nodes whose values need to be changed using their xpath, this is a given business case for me that I cannot change.

Comment: Yes. But when you have a program in, for the sake of the argument, VBScript, then you can use the XPath strings you have to actually find according nodes in your DOMDocument (via `xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(xPathString)`) and then fill in the corresponding value right in VBScript. That's way easier than doing it in XSLT, because XSLT does not support dynamic XPath evaluation.

Comment: how is that related to my problem? I only have xslt in a server environment that I cannot change, the xpath for the nodes that need to be replaced are provided to me before each release, I channot change the input xml neither can I programatically do anhting excpet xslt 1.0 from MS

Comment: Well, I figured if you can run XSLT then you maybe can run something else as well. I was trying to make sure you are not fixed on XSLT "just because". You could also think about running XSLT with a [script extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms256042.aspx) to do the XPath evaluation, for example. Not being able to dynamically evaluate an XPath string is your main issue here, a script would solve that very nicely (and efficiently).

Comment: I've built a proof-of-concept solution to show you what I mean. See my answer.

Comment: Do you think you can use the proposal? It's been quite a while without any kind of feedback now.

Comment: @Tomalak, I will check your proposal when I have time, at the moment I am working on other things, I will cerainly updated the entry here when I get the results, many thanks for your time and assistance!

Answer (score 2):

> I compute the xpath for the current node then do one of the following...

This is likely to be your inefficiency - if you're recalculating the path right back to the root every time you're likely to be looking at an O(N<sup>2</sup>) algorithm.  Without seeing your XSLT this is rather speculative, but you might be able to trim this a bit by using parameters to pass the current path down the recursion - if your main algorithm is based on a standard identity template

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

then change it to something like

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:param name="curPath" />
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
      <xsl:with-param name="curPath" select="concat($curPath, '/', name())" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

or whatever your logic is for building the paths you need.  Now in your specific templates for the nodes you want to massage you already have the path to their parent node and you don't have to walk all the way up to the root every time.

You might need to add a

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

so you don't get a double slash at the front of `$curPath`

---

> The xpaths are hardcoded in the xslt as a string in a global variable

If instead of a string you represented this mapping in an XML structure then you could make use of the *key* mechanism to speed up your lookups:

```
<xsl:variable name="rtfLookupTable">
  <lookuptable>
    <val xpath="/first/xpath/expression" id="1" />
    <val xpath="/second/xpath/expression" id="2" />
    <!-- ... -->
  </lookuptable>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="lookupTable" select="msxsl:node-set($rtfLookupTable)" />

<xsl:key name="valByXpath" match="val" use="@xpath" />
```

(add `xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"` to your `xsl:stylesheet`).  Or if you want to avoid using the `node-set` extension function then an alternative definition could be

```
<xsl:variable name="lookupTable" select="document('')//xsl:variable[name='rtfLookupTable']" />
```

which works by treating the stylesheet itself as a plain XML document.

Keys across multiple documents get a bit fiddly in XSLT 1.0 but it can be done, essentially you have to switch the current context to point to the `$lookupTable` before calling the key function, so you need to save the current context in variables to let you refer to it later:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:param name="curPath" />

  <xsl:variable name="dot" select="." />
  <xsl:variable name="slash" select="/" />

  <xsl:for-each select="$lookupTable">
    <xsl:variable name="valId" select="key('valByXpath', $curPath)/@id" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$valId">
        <xsl:value-of select="$slash//Value[@id = $valId]" />
        <!-- or however you extract the right Value -->
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$dot" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Or indeed, why not just let the XSLT engine do the hard work for you.  Rather than representing your mapping as a string

```
/path/to/node1_1:/path/to/node2_2
```

represent it as templates directly

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <!-- copy everything as-is apart from exceptions below -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- delete the RealValuesRoot -->
  <xsl:template match="RealValuesRoot" />

  <xsl:template match="/path/to/node1">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:value-of select="//Value[id='1']" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/path/to/node2">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:value-of select="//Value[id='2']" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm sure you can see how the specific templates could easily be auto-generated from your existing mapping using some sort of template mechanism (which could even be another XSLT).

Comment: Your idea of building the xpath is great!
JFYI, the performance killer in my case ist not the xpath building, it is instead the concat() function that needs to look up an xpath string in a huge string>

Comment: @Siraf where do the XPaths come into it?  How do you build up your "global string variable" in the first place?  Do the real `Value` elements in your document have the XPath as an attribute or is the ID->XPath mapping held in an external file?  I'm trying to work out whether there's any way to leverage the _key_ mechanism to speed up these lookups.

Comment: I like the idea of building xpath using the template.
JFYI: my performance bottleneck is not the xpath concatenation.

Comment: The xpaths are hardcoded in the xslt as a string in a global variable.

The "<Value>" nodes have an ID that relates to the xpath in the global id-xpath string>

33% of the performance at the moment is wasted in the contains string function that looks up the xpath of the current node in the global large (view KB) xpath string

Comment: @Siraf I've outlined a way you might be able to attack this using a key.

Comment: Thanks Ian! unfortuantely I cannot use a variable with xml content because I cannot use the Microsoft function "node-set()", I have to use Microsoft's xslt 1.0 WITHOUT MS specific extensions because the xslt also has to work on another platform :-\

Comment: @Siraf given that the XML is completely static (not generated using XSL instructions) an alternative definition for the `lookupTable` variable would be `<xsl:variable name="lookupTable" select="document('')//xsl:variable[name='rtfLookupTable']"/>`, which treats the stylesheet XML document itself as just another XML file.  This should work on any processor provided the processor knows the system ID (i.e. the URL) of the stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to go about this is to use an XSL key.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- a key that indexes real values by their IDs -->
  <xsl:key name="kRealVal" match="RealValuesRoot/Value" use="@ID" />

  <!-- the identity template to copy everything -->    
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- ...except elements named <NodeX> -->
  <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'Node')]">
    <xsl:variable name="myID" select="substring-after(name(), 'Node')" />
    <xsl:variable name="myRealVal" select="key('kRealVal', $myID)" />

    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$myRealVal">
          <xsl:value-of select="$myRealVal" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- the <RealValuesRoot> element can be trashed -->
  <xsl:template match="RealValuesRoot" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the live preview of this solution: http://www.xmlplayground.com/R78v0n

---

Here is a proof-of-concept solution that uses Microsoft script extensions to do the heavy lifting:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:script="http://tempuri.org/script"
>  
  <msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="script">
    var index = {};

    function getNode(context, xpath) {
      var theContext = context[0],
          theXpath = xpath[0].text,
          result;

      try {
        result = theContext.selectSingleNode(theXpath)
      } catch (ex) {
        // xpath is invalid. we could also just throw here
        // but lets return the empty node set.
        result = theContext.selectSingleNode("*[false()]");
      }
      return result;
    }
    function buildIndex(id, node) {
      var theNode = node[0];

      if (id) index[id] = theNode;
      return "";
    }
    function getValue(id) {
      return (id in index) ? index[id] : '';
    }
  </msxsl:script>


  <!-- this is the boilerplate to evaluate all the XPaths -->
  <xsl:variable name="temp">
    <xsl:for-each select="/root/source/map">
      <xsl:value-of select="script:buildIndex(generate-id(script:getNode(/, @xpath)), .)" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>

  <!-- the identity template to get things rolling -->
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- actually evaluate $temp once, so the variable is being calculated -->
    <xsl:value-of select="$temp" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
  </xsl:template> 

  <!-- all <value> nodes do either have a related "actual value" or they are copied as they are -->
  <xsl:template match="value">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />

      <xsl:variable name="newValue" select="script:getValue(generate-id())" />
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$newValue">
          <xsl:value-of select="$newValue" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- the <source> element can be dropped -->
  <xsl:template match="source" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It transforms

```
<root>
  <value id="foo">this is to be replaced</value>

  <source>
    <map xpath="/root/value[@id = 'foo']">this is the new value</map>
  </source>
</root>
```

to

```
<root>
  <value id="foo">this is the new value</value>
</root>
```

Maybe you can go that route in your set-up.

The line of thought is this:

- Iterate all XPaths you have, evaluating them with `.selectSingleNode()`.
- Store each evaluation result (one node, ideally) along with its unique ID in an object as key-value pairs. This uses XSLT's `generate-id()` to get an ID from a node.
- Now transform the input normally. For each node in question, get its ID and check if a "new value" actually exists for that node.
- If it does, insert that new value, if it doesn't, go on transforming.

Tested successfully with msxsl.exe.

Of course this assumes that the input has those `<map xpath="...">` elements, but that part is not really necessary and easily adaptable to your actual situation. You could build the `index` object from a long string of XPaths that you `split()` in JavaScript, for example.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to develop a solution!
I am afraid that you missed something in your solution, in my case I have to identify the nodes whose value needs to be replaced by their xpath! this is something given for me that I cannot change! this means that I have to construct the xpath for each node then look that xpath up in a huge xpath-id lookup string that is hardcoded as a global variable in the xslt itself.

Comment: Oh God. :D Yes, then I have misunderstood the requirement. To me it looked like a simple mapping job (map ID `X` from here to node `X` from there). I will give the problem another thought. You would make my life easier if you [pasted](http://pastebin.com/) stripped down (but live!) examples for me to use.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to develop a solution!

Your solution is missing something, the nodes that need to be replaced  must be identified by their xpath, this is why I have a global variable that contains all the xpath and id pairs, for each node I have to check if its xpath exists in the list or not.

Using this global xpath list I doubled the performance by simply copying the current node (with children) when its xpath does not exist in the list.

I am wondering if my transformation can be implemented without recursive iteration?

Comment: I am sorry I cannot do that, you know it is company data, I hope you understand.

Comment: I understand. But you can set up an example with bogus data that just works along the same principles, can't you?